# Laravel 5.2 project copied from LAMP to WAMP not working properly

Tags: php, laravel-5, wamp, lamp

I am a beginner in `Laravel 5.2`. I started it in `Linux mint - LAMP` and which is working perfectly. Now I tried to move it to `WAMP` in `Windows 10`. I got all the pages. But the issue is, when I try to login, the router function for `POST` is not working. It is always leading to the `GET` function in the router file.

**The router function is like**

```
Route::post('/', 'Controller_name@post_function_name');
Route::get('/', 'Controller_name@function_name');
```

Only the 'get' function working at the time of post.

**The steps I did are**

> 1) Installed WAMP in windows 10.
>
> 2) Installed `Composer` globally.
>
> 3) Copied the entire `Larevel` folder to `www` directory.
>
> 4) Tried to access the URL : http://localhost/laravel/public

The first page is coming. But the form submit is not working. Am I missing something?

Please help. Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the `php.ini` for all dependencies and configured your local webserver? If your code isn't broken it's your environment.

Comment: @Soundz, What are all the things I need to do? Can you please explain? I am not aware about such things

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all check your `php.ini` it should be in the php-directory of wamp

Then check if you have the following extensions enabled by removing the ; in front of `;extension=php_xxx.dll`:

```
PHP >= 5.6.4
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
```

Next check your apache settings for this on the directory settings

```
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

If everything is correct do a simple php script to check the post data

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['foo']) 
{
  echo '<h1>Works</h1>';
  die;
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="foo" value="test" />
</form>
```

if that succeeds try empting laravel caches and the like

`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan clear-compiled`

If it still doesn't work report again

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I will check it for sure and let you know